# Sumar los valores de muchos Texbox y colocar el valor en un Texbox C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hola estimados como están estoy implemtendo un cierre de caja y tengo este formulario, les muestro esta imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora, como verán funciona correctamente,pero. me gustaría que me den sus puntos de vista de que esta o no bien implementado. tengo todo este código para hacer ese trabajo

```
private void BsDoscientos()
    {
        if (this.textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            _Valor = textBox1.Text;
            _Tag = Lbl200bs.Tag.ToString();
            Resultado = decimal.Parse(_Valor) * decimal.Parse(_Tag);
            Lbl200R.Text = Resultado.ToString();
            Suma();
        }
        else
        {
            Lbl200R.Text = 0.ToString();
            Suma();
            return;
        }
    }
    private void BsCien()
    {
        string ValorTexto = Txt100.Text;
        if (ValorTexto != "")
        {
            _Valor = ValorTexto;
            _Tag = Lbl100Bs.Tag.ToString();
            Resultado = decimal.Parse(_Valor) * decimal.Parse(_Tag);
            Lbl100R.Text = Resultado.ToString();
            Suma();
        }
        else
        {
            Lbl100R.Text = 0.ToString();
            Suma();
            return;
        }
    }
    private void BsCincuenta()
    {
        string ValorTexto = Txt50.Text;
        if (ValorTexto != "")
        {
            _Valor = ValorTexto;
            _Tag = Lbl50Bs.Tag.ToString();
            Resultado = decimal.Parse(_Valor) * decimal.Parse(_Tag);
            Lbl50R.Text = Resultado.ToString();
            Suma();
        }
        else
        {
            Lbl50R.Text = 0.ToString();
            Suma();
            return;
        }
    }
    private void BsVeinte()
    {
        string ValorTexto = Txt20.Text;
        if (ValorTexto != "")
        {
            _Valor = ValorTexto;
            _Tag = Lbl20Bs.Tag.ToString();
            Resultado = decimal.Parse(_Valor) * decimal.Parse(_Tag);
            Lbl20R.Text = Resultado.ToString();
            Suma();
        }
        else
        {
            Lbl20R.Text = 0.ToString();
            Suma();
            return;
        }
    }
    private void BsDiez()
    {
        string ValorTexto = Txt10.Text;
        if (ValorTexto != "")
        {
            _Valor = ValorTexto;
            _Tag = Lbl10Bs.Tag.ToString();
            Resultado = decimal.Parse(_Valor) * decimal.Parse(_Tag);
            Lbl10R.Text = Resultado.ToString();
            Suma();
        }
        else
        {
            Lbl10R.Text = 0.ToString();
            Suma();
            return;
        }
    }
    private void BsCinco()
    {
        string ValorTexto = Txt5.Text;
        if (ValorTexto != "")
        {
            _Valor = ValorTexto;
            _Tag = Lbl5Bs.Tag.ToString();
            Resultado = decimal.Parse(_Valor) * decimal.Parse(_Tag);
            Lbl5R.Text = Resultado.ToString();
            Suma();
        }
        else
        {
            Lbl5R.Text = 0.ToString();
            Suma();
            return;
        }
    }
    private void BsDos()
    {
        string ValorTexto = Txt2.Text;
        if (ValorTexto != "")
        {
            _Valor = ValorTexto;
            _Tag = Lbl2Bs.Tag.ToString();
            Resultado = decimal.Parse(_Valor) * decimal.Parse(_Tag);
            Lbl2R.Text = Resultado.ToString();
            Suma();
        }
        else
        {
            Lbl2R.Text = 0.ToString();
            Suma();
            return;
        }
    }
    private void BsUno()
    {
        string ValorTexto = Txt1.Text;
        if (ValorTexto != "")
        {
            _Valor = ValorTexto;
            _Tag = Lbl1Bs.Tag.ToString();
            Resultado = decimal.Parse(_Valor) * decimal.Parse(_Tag);
            Lbl1R.Text = Resultado.ToString();
            Suma();
        }
        else
        {
            Lbl1R.Text = 0.ToString();
            Suma();
            return;
        }
    }
    private void CincuentaCentavos()
    {
        string ValorTexto = Txt050.Text;
        if (ValorTexto != "")
        {
            _Valor = ValorTexto;
            _Tag = Lbl050Bs.Tag.ToString();
            Resultado = decimal.Parse(_Valor) * decimal.Parse(_Tag);
            Lbl050R.Text = Resultado.ToString();
            Suma();
        }
        else
        {
            Lbl050R.Text = 0.ToString();
            Suma();
            return;
        }
    }
    private void VeinteCentavos()
    {
        string ValorTexto = Txt020Ctvo.Text;
        if (ValorTexto != "")
        {
            _Valor = ValorTexto;
            _Tag = Lbl020Ctv.Tag.ToString();
            Resultado = decimal.Parse(_Valor) * decimal.Parse(_Tag);
            Lbl020CtvoR.Text = Resultado.ToString();
            Suma();
        }
        else
        {
            Lbl020CtvoR.Text = 0.ToString();
            Suma();
            return;
        }
    }
    private void DiezCentavos()
    {
        string ValorTexto = Txt010Ctvo.Text;
        if (ValorTexto != "")
        {
            _Valor = ValorTexto;
            _Tag = Lbl010Ctvo.Tag.ToString();
            Resultado = decimal.Parse(_Valor) * decimal.Parse(_Tag);
            Lbl010R.Text = Resultado.ToString();
            Suma();
        }
        else
        {
            Lbl010R.Text = 0.ToString();
            Suma();
            return;
        }
    }


    private void Txt100_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BsCien();
    }

    private void Txt50_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BsCincuenta();
    }

    private void Txt20_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BsVeinte();
    }

    private void Txt10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BsDiez();
    }

    private void Txt5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BsCinco();
    }

    private void Txt2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BsDos();
    }

    private void Txt1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BsUno();
    }

    private void Txt050_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CincuentaCentavos();
    }

    private void Txt020Ctvo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VeinteCentavos();
    }

    private void Txt010Ctvo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DiezCentavos();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BsDoscientos();
    }
```

y para la suma tengo este método,

```
private void Suma()
    {
        decimal Doscientos = decimal.Parse(Lbl200R.Text);
        decimal Cien = decimal.Parse(Lbl100R.Text);
        decimal Cincuenta = decimal.Parse(Lbl50R.Text);
        decimal Veinte = decimal.Parse(Lbl20R.Text);
        decimal Diez = decimal.Parse(Lbl10R.Text);
        decimal Cinco = decimal.Parse(Lbl5R.Text);
        decimal Dos = decimal.Parse(Lbl2R.Text);
        decimal Un = decimal.Parse(Lbl1R.Text);
        decimal CeroCincuenta = decimal.Parse(Lbl050R.Text);
        decimal CeroVeinte = decimal.Parse(Lbl020CtvoR.Text);
        decimal CeroDiez = decimal.Parse(Lbl010R.Text);
        Total = Doscientos + Cien + Cincuenta + Veinte + Diez + Cinco + Dos + Un + CeroCincuenta + CeroVeinte + CeroDiez;
        //TxtTotal.Text = Total.ToString("###0,00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        TxtTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:n2}", Total, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

ahora para pasar de un texbox a otro tengo este método que funciona perfectamente

```
private void FrmCerrarCaja_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar((Keys.Enter)))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        }
    }
```

y ahora tengo un problema, y es que me permite ingresar letras y signos negativos y me manda una exepcion.
tengo este código en otro formulario el cual impide que ingrese letras y signos y solo habilita la tecla retroceso.

```
private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //Para obligar a que sólo se introduzcan números
        if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
          if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) //permitir teclas de control como retroceso
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //el resto de teclas pulsadas se desactivan
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

ahora lo que había pensado es crear un evento keypress y llamarlo, pero aquí viene mi segunda pregunta, porque la primera es si el código anterior esta bien implementado o si hay como optimizarlo, y la pregunta es. Como hago eso, ya que de hacerlo de uno en uno se imaginan cuantos keypress debo abrir, osea el de cada texbox y agregar el código en cada evento de cada texbox.
por favor me puede ayudar a resolver este problema que tengo .
agradezco por la ayuda.
Rob
Les aclaro nuevamente que el evento este yo lo cree porque en otro formulario si funciona para un texbox. pero ahora son varios.

```
private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

{
}
Lo llame Texbox_KeyPres por llamarlo e identificarlo

Comment: todo se puede hacer con solo 2 metodos.. no esas reutilizando codigo .. dejame te armo una respuesta aunque la pregunta podia ser basada en opiniones

Comment: Claro, agradezco por todas las opiniones.

Comment: Si necesitas mas ayuda, podes encontrarla en el [chat]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los metodos en c# (o en vb.net) son reutilizables...

eso quiere decir, que el metodo keypress de un textbox, puede atender a cualquier textbox.

Este metodo:

```
private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

Recibe dos cosas, un sender de tipo objeto, que es nada mas ni nada menos que el control que ejecuta el evento, y e, que es de tipo KeyPressEventArgs que son parametros del evento.

O sea, podes usar un solo evento para todos los textbox... como el sender es de tipo textbox, en tu codigo podes hacer algo asi

```
TextBox EsteControl = (TextBox) sender;
```

Y ya sabes de que TextBox estas hablando...

Fijate que igual tu codigo no lo necesita, porque usa e para trabajar, y e ya sabe en que textbox esta ;)

Aparte de eso, veamos tus metodos que pasan datos de izquierda a derecha...

Todos esos metodos se pueden resumir en uno solo, aprovechando el tag del control y teniendo un array de datos para saber que hacer en cada caso...

Agarremos uno cualquiera:

```
string ValorTexto = Txt20.Text;
if (ValorTexto != "")
{
    _Valor = ValorTexto;
    _Tag = Lbl20Bs.Tag.ToString();
    Resultado = decimal.Parse(_Valor) * decimal.Parse(_Tag);
    Lbl20R.Text = Resultado.ToString();
    Suma();
}
else
{
    Lbl20R.Text = 0.ToString();
    Suma();
    return;
}
```

Y veamos quien lo llama:

```
private void Txt100_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BsCien();
}
```

Ese metodo TextChanged se puede generalizar (ya sabes como) y llamar a un metodo generico Transformar, que reciba, el textbox de la izquierda, el de la derecha (podrias tener un array con esa informacion ya pre-cargado) y en el tag poner por ejemplo el indice de ese array.

Y tu metodo generico seria algo asi:

```
private void Transformar(TextBox izquierda, TextBox derecha, int multiplicador)
{
    // hacer la transformacion
}
```